# Pointer Truncation from void* to DWORD

Tags: c++, pointers, windows-10, truncate

I am using a [control library](https://github.com/yoggy/nanoKONTROL2-lib) for Visual C++ for a Project, which works perfect if I build it in the x32 Version. For my Project, I need it to be x64, so I tried to compile it with x64 in Visual Studio. But I am getting some Warnings:

[image: Warnings]

This is Line 17.

```
    rv = midiInOpen(&handle_, device_idx, (DWORD)(void*)midi_in_proc_static_, (DWORD_PTR)this, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
```

How can I change that to a x64 Version? And do I have to change something in the Project Proberties?

Comment: Pointers on x64 are 64 bits long, a MS-Windows `DWORD` is 32 bits.  You need to look at the API spec ... Just looked, it's not a `DWORD` but a `DWORD_PTR` (same as param 4) see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798458(v=vs.85).aspx . You need to change your cast,

Comment: Show your error messages as _text_, not an image.

Comment: @RichardCritten I changed `DWORD` to `LONGLONG` and `DWORD_PTR` to `LONG_PTR`, which works!

Comment: You should cast to the correct types as linked in my comment above.  Just because it compiles does not mean you have the correct cast.

Comment: Get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you're doing it wrong. [Here's the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798458(v=vs.85).aspx) about `midiInOpen()` funtion.

Its prototype is:

```
MMRESULT midiInOpen(
   LPHMIDIIN lphMidiIn,
   UINT      uDeviceID,
   DWORD_PTR dwCallback, // This is DWORD_PTR not DWORD
   DWORD_PTR dwCallbackInstance,
   DWORD     dwFlags
);
```

So it just makes no sense to convert `void*` to `DWORD` which isn't the expected type. You should convert it directly into `DWORD_PTR`.

Answer (score 1):

With the modern windows API you should use DWORD_PTR for this sort of thing, it will be either 32 or 64 bits depending on build settings. If the library specifies DWORD and you can't rebuild you may well not be able to use it in 64 bit builds.

Comment: See my comment it's a WIN32API call, OP has just used the wrong cast.